# Code to parse user agent string?

Tags: php, parsing, user-agent, string-parsing

As strange as I find this, I have not been able to find a good PHP function anywhere which will do an intelligent parse of a user agent string? Googled it for about 20 minutes now.

I have the string already, I just need something that will chop it up and give me at least browser/ver/os.

Know of a good snippet anywhere?

Comment: Yes, I know I can write my own, but I really don't have time at the moment. I need something I can plug in and use to finish up this project.

Comment: get_browser() is quiet old and slow. Use one of the parser here http://github.com/ThaDafinser/UserAgentParser

Comment: warning against using the suggested library above (TheDafinser). It seems to work by pushing a request to another site (http://www.useragentstring.com/) which as we speak is DOWN!!!! Since I was using it somewhere, it slowed my site like nobody's business since the request had to run until timeout. Be warned

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function has been available in PHP for quite a long a time.

The PHP manual is free, can be downloaded in various formats and viewed online (with comments)

Comment: This would be a perfect example of how being up for more than two days can affect memory and cause you to ask extremely stupid questions about functions you already know about. :) Thanks

Comment: The post below (https://github.com/garetjax/phpbrowscap) is what the PHP manual suggests.

Comment: Is there any performance penalty when enabling `get_browser()` function in php ?

Comment: @Bhavesh: that's a very complex question. Fortunately it has a very simple answer: measure it :)

Comment: Forget to mention that in order to use that function you need a ~10MB php_browscap.ini file. - Otherwise this error will occur: `browscap ini directive not set`

Comment: get_browser() is quiet old and slow. Use one of the parser here https://github.com/ThaDafinser/UserAgentParser

Comment: None of these solutions work when processing a remote request e.g. like from an API. So, given we have the user agent string (from `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`), how can we parse it?

Comment: All of these solutions are predicated on parsing `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` - if the available parsers are not working then you don't have a user agent string in $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

Answer (score 12):

https://github.com/browscap/browscap-php - this is a standalone library that aims to replace `get_browser` function. For shared hostings it seems to be a better option.

Works on: PHP 5

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use: https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser. This is multi-language tool to parsing user agent string. For PHP is here: https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser/tree/master/php

Answer (score 0):

Try out [ThaDafinser/UserAgentParser](https://github.com/ThaDafinser/UserAgentParser) it's an abstraction for many available user agent parsers.

So if you are not happy with one - just switch to another (or combine them)

You can [try it out here](http://useragent.mkf.solutions/)

Comment: gave me very many issues when the website they throw the processing requests to was down. It slowed my site badly.

Comment: Then you might used a remote parser like "http://useragentstring.com/" (which is down lately). Of course that will then slow your website down. You can use a local parser when you rely on speed. See https://github.com/ThaDafinser/UserAgentParser#local-providers

Answer (score 0):

There is a PHP class library i found out, and it has worked so well for me. It is in the link below.

https://www.toms-world.org/blog/parseuseragentstring

It is lightweight and just does what I wanted (Browser, Version, OS, Mobile/PC, and much more) in a memory-friendy manner.