# Useragent parsing library for PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, user-agent

Do you know library for PHP that might help with parsing useragent string from browser? I want to extract at least those features:

- language
- browser (name and version)
- os (name and version)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a partial duplicate of [Code to parse user agent string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122786/code-to-parse-user-agent-string)

You can use the get_browser() function in PHP to parse the user-agent header and retrieve the browser and the OS versions.

However, the language information is not sent as part of the user-agent string. Instead, you probably want to look at the "Accept-Languagr" header, i.e. $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]

Comment: get_browser() is quiet old and slow. Use one of the parser here https://github.com/ThaDafinser/UserAgentParser

Answer (score 3):

You can use [get_browser()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php). Just make sure your database (the *browscap.ini* file)  is up-to-date.