# browsers user agent list

Tags: php

I'm using function to detect my website visitors browser type but later i found there many visits comes with undetectable browsers so i might needs to do some update to my browsers user agent list.

this is my list of browsers with browser name as array key and user agent as value.

```
$browsers = array(
                'Opera' => 'Opera',
                'Mozilla Firefox'=> '(Firebird)|(Firefox)',
                'Galeon' => 'Galeon',
                'Mozilla'=>'Gecko',
                'MyIE'=>'MyIE',
                'Lynx' => 'Lynx',
                'Netscape' => '(Mozilla/4\.75)|(Netscape6)|(Mozilla/4\.08)|(Mozilla/4\.5)|(Mozilla/4\.6)|(Mozilla/4\.79)',
                'Konqueror'=>'Konqueror',
                'SearchBot' => '(nuhk)|(Googlebot)|(Yammybot)|(Openbot)|(Slurp/cat)|(msnbot)|(ia_archiver)',
                'Internet Explorer 8' => '(MSIE 8\.[0-9]+)',
                'Internet Explorer 7' => '(MSIE 7\.[0-9]+)',
                'Internet Explorer 6' => '(MSIE 6\.[0-9]+)',
                'Internet Explorer 5' => '(MSIE 5\.[0-9]+)',
                'Internet Explorer 4' => '(MSIE 4\.[0-9]+)',
);
```

my question is where to get more browsers name / user agent !
for example for safari,navigator,mosaic,lynx,amaya,omniweb,avant,camino ..etc.

Comment: many result in google search, do use Google Analytics it provides you with information of what device/browser the visitor is using

Comment: UA sniffing is evil. Do not do it. If like so many others you choose to ignore that rule and do it anyway, at least do it properly: [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/get-browser)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code to parse user agent string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122786/code-to-parse-user-agent-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use php's [get_browser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

The following site has a list of User-Agents for (Spiders, Robots, Crawler, Browser)

http://www.user-agents.org/

Answer (score 0):

I have a list.. hope it works for u as well [Browser List](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/design/browsers_list.php3)