# How to give option to my web users of download my Android app

Tags: android, redirect, web, download

I have created my Android app with androidcreator.com and I have downloaded it.

Now I want to show to my web users that visit my web from an Android device the option of download the app when they visit my website.

My website uses php. Exists an "standard" php/javascript code to ask to my web users for download the Android app? (Only when they come from an Android device)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple add link to Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be more proactive, you can check the user agent string from the client in PHP for 'Android' and use that to popup something to encourage them to download your app.

See:
[Code to parse user agent string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122786/code-to-parse-user-agent-string)

Comment: Thanks Morrison, I will continue looking for a solution basing in your reply.