# How to get user used browser name in .net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, web, .net-core, http-headers, browser-detection

I am using the code below:

```
Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString()
```

But it's giving me all browser details despite I only want the browser name.

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Comment: This might help you: https://github.com/totpero/DeviceDetector.NET

Comment: but for that i have to install some packages ,is it any other way to do this ..?

Comment: User agent strings are notoriously hard to manage. It will take a long time to develop your own solution.

Comment: see if this is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063499/how-to-read-useragent-details

Answer (score 1):

User-Agent strings can come in various form, so it's better to use an API such as [User Agent Parsing API](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/api/features/user-agent-parse) to get better results.

You've not explained us why you want to detect the browser. But take some time to read [MDN advices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent) about/against browser detection:

> Using the user agent to detect the browser looks simple, but doing it
>   well is, in fact, a very hard problem. This document will guide you in
>   doing this as correctly as possible.