# How to understand and get information from a log string

Tags: browser, user-agent, access-log

I have a user log example like this:

```
141.154.49.202 - - [21/Jul/2021:14:26:42 +0000] 
"GET /projects/operation/report/index.htm?product=home&msid=fg552595-976c-58dg-0689-c3d8ffb0d904&zip=90221&ho_prod=G&prog_status=ghsdsq&track_id=89e05bmb3eg05fef095929d1c39106&cust_id=&quoteStartID=916d1b0d-118f056g2-0705-916bgdd4bf47 HTTP/1.1"
 302 5 
"https://www.yourwebiste.com/" 
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 13_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.2.3 Mobile/26F259 Safari/715.2" 0.029 0.000 0.029 0.029 -
```

Based on the following answers, I got part of the information from the log

1. [How to read useragent details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063499/how-to-read-useragent-details)
2. [Understanding Apache's access log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234699/understanding-apaches-access-log)

Here are what I got:

- 141.154.49.202: user IP address
- [21/Jul/2021:14:26:42 +0000]: date, time and timezone
- Mozilla/5.0: product
- iPad; CPU OS 13_5 like Mac OS X: device and system-information
- AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.2.3: platform and details
- Mobile/26F259: device type
- Safari/715.2: browser information

Now, my question is what the rest of the log stands for? Specifically,

- What are the two URLs (first: "GET URL HTTP/1.1"; second: "www.yourwebiste.com/") mean? I guess one is the page user visit, but what is the another?
- What is the meaning of 302 5 between two URLs?
- what is the series of numbers at the end(0.029 0.000 0.029 0.029) refers to

Comment: 2 of the 3 questions you asked are already answered by the link `Understanding Apache access log` you have posted. The first URL is the URL that was hit (= the client visits) and the second one is the Referrer so the URL from which the request was initiated. 302 is the HTTP response code and 5 the number of bytes sent.

Comment: Hi Mushroomator, Thank you for your comment. I found that one answer in the "understanding apache access log" gave a link about the full format introduction of a log file, which provides answers about quesiton1, and 2.  But I still cannot find any information about my question 3.