# Discerning demographics of website visitors from user agent strings in table?

Tags: php, mysql, analytics, frontend, user-agent

I have a db table that captures visitor info, including a user agent string. I'm trying to determine the demographics of browsers in order to prioritize web testing on higher incidence browsers/versions.

My question: user agents appear very similar to me; is there any way I can write a query to differentiate the strings into their representative browsers/versions?

Thanks in advance.

Note: my company does not have google analytics configured to track this info, and we need to measure data on file rather than waiting for new visitors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code to parse user agent string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122786/code-to-parse-user-agent-string)

Comment: Yes and no. Yes you can parse them and guess at what browser are being used, however, that also is becoming less and less reliable and is in no way future proof because each new version of a browser or each different environment that the browser runs in may have a different useragent. IE11 for example. Good luck figuring out which user-agents are for IE11

Comment: You could write a script to iterate over each DB record and send/post the data to GA including IP and [Useragent](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ua).